# unique identifier for a DOS process on 1 single machine

Tags: process

I use a Win 10 machine with different users, and these all can use a same bat file.

In the bat scripts I need a temporary file with an unique name consisting of an identfier for the process currently at hand on that machine. There thus can be multiple such processes at the same time.

As file name a want to use C:\Windows\Temp\???.txt.

The question is what ??? must be.

Comment: You should never put your own files in C:\Windows. Why don't you put these files in %USERPROFILE% ?

Comment: Or some completely different folder that can be accessed by everyone. What does "process currently at hand" mean? Why can't you name the file with whatever unique identifier you want?

Comment: The command at hand is i_view64.exe, the 64 bit bitmap image editor Irfanview. I use it as follows: `i_view64.exe inputfile.jpg /info=???.txt`. ??? must cover different users on that same machine, and also multiple such commands by the same user on that same machine. Under *NIX/POSIX this is $$. I don't know what it is on DOS.

Comment: I also want to use `C:\` because that partition on the multitask/multiuser PC is on a SSD drive and this is faster than the other HDD's of that PC. Under *NIX one has /tmp/$$ for a fast drive. On that PC machine it is the SSD which is fastest. The i_view64.exe command makes part of bat scripts that contain FOR commands on eg 380 .png files. This thakes easily 10 minutes. I have a virtual *NIX on that PC, but I don't want to use it. I want to use DOS because that Win 10 PC is mainly DOS based.

Comment: So using `C:\Windows\Temp\IrfanView\%USERPROFILE%\info_???.txt` would be a first attempt. In that case one only have to take into account ??? for the different processes started up by the same user at the same time on that machine.

Comment: On that system my account is located at %USERPROFILE% which is equal to "C\Users\Francky Leyn", and thus on that C:\ SSD of that machine. So "%USERPROFILE%\tmp\IrfanView\info_???.txt"  would do the job, if I know what ??? must be.

Answer (score 0):

### The Answer

If you want to use the PID of cmd.exe then do this:

```
title=uniqueTitle
for /f "tokens=2 USEBACKQ" %f IN (`tasklist /NH /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq uniqueTitle*"`) Do set ourPID=%f
i_view64.exe inputfile.jpg /info=%temp%\%ourPID%.txt
```

**Me rambling because I didn't understand the question:**

In the context of a batch file running the "current process at hand" is that of the command interpreter (conhost.exe or cmd.exe). If you want to get the process ID of the i_view64.exe you would have to first run it and then get the process ID (which is non-trivial). In your case you are asking for the process ID before it has been created. There is no way to predict what it will be at the time you are feeding a command line argument to the process, as it hasn't started.

If you just want a unique temporary file name in a safe, reliable location then you should check out this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802376/create-unique-file-name-windows-batch

There are a number of suggested solutions.

Generally you use %TEMP% to get the temp location on the system. Then you generate your filename.

something like this might work for you:

```
%temp%\%username%-%date%-%random%.txt
```

Adjust as needed. Each of those variables expand to create a full path to a file.

Comment: I use it in the bat file `get_resolution.bat` which contains:

Comment: `i_view64.exe jpg_inputfile.jpg /info=textfile.txt`. So, I do not need the process ID of `i_view64.exe`. I need the process ID of the calling script `get_resolution.bat`.

Comment: Do I have to use `%USERNAME%`? "`echo %TEMP%`" is equal to `C:\Users\FRANCK~1\AppData\Local\Temp`. What means that "`~`" anyway? "`echo %USERNAME%`" delivers "`Francky Leyn`"

Comment: `CALL i_view64.exe "input.jpg" /info=%TEMP%\IrfanView\info_%DATE%-%TIME%-%RANDOM%.txt"` delivers `CALL i_view64.exe "input.jpg" /info="C:\Users\FRANCK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IrfanView\info_Fri 11/16/2018- 9:44:27.14-13375.txt"`. Why the space after `%DATE%-`?

Comment: K:\test>ECHO %TIME%  
    12:38:21.00

Comment: This can never work, because  ":" is no a valid NTFS filename character.

Comment: @FranckyLeyn I understand now. I put the answer you need on the top of my post.